# How to push data into SC.SourceListView

Tags: sproutcore, sproutcore-views, sproutcore-controllers

I want to push some parsed JSON data from my controller into a `SC.SourceListView`[(Sproutcore Showcase)](http://showcase.sproutcore.com/). I use a `SC.TreeController` and set the parsed JSON as content:

```
MyApp.thisController = SC.TreeController.create({
    treeItemChildrenKey: 'children',
    content: []
});
```

The property `treeItemChild` is set accordingly to the property in the objects and leads to the child objects.

The content in the `SC.TreeController` contains several objects (JSON data) which base on the following structure (this is an example of one of those objects I want to push into the tree view):

```
children: Array[3]
    0: Object
        children: Array[1]
        data: "Boogie"
        metadata: Object
        __proto__: Object
    1: Object
    2: Object
data: "Blues"
metadata: Object
__proto__: Object
```

I want to put the `data` property in my `SC.SourceListView` so that it reads.

```
Blues
    Boogie
    ...
    ...
```

This content is now binded to the `SC.SourceListView` and should show the `data` property on the screen:

```
viewname: SC.SourceListView.extend({
    contentBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('MyApp.thisController.arrangedObjects'),
    exampleView: SC.ListItemView.extend({
        contentValueKey: 'data'
    }),
    groupExampleView: SC.ListItemView.extend({
        contentValueKey: 'data'
    })
})
```

With this I am able to get the `data` of the top layer of the different objects. But there is no dropdown, which consists of the objects in the deeper layers. How do I set up this view properly? What is the difference between `SC.SourceListView` and `SC.SourceListGroupView`?

[(Google Group Link)](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sproutcore/A7tw9k0lIa8)

Answer (score 0):

The `SC.SourceListGroupView` is the actual list-item view used to render the group within the `SC.SourceListView`. Currently, you're using

```
groupExampleView: SC.ListItemView.extend()
```

However, `SC.ListItemView` doesn't, by default, know how to render itself as a group, so you should probably change this to

```
groupExampleView: SC.SourceListGroupView.extend()
```

After that, it should show you the tree.

Lastly (and I'm assuming this is just a typo in the question): you have

```
MyApp.thisController.anrrangedObjects
```

I'm pretty sure you really meant

```
MyApp.thisController.arrangedObjects
```

Please add a comment or update your question if changing it to `SC.SourceListGroupView` doesn't solve your problem! If you still need help, it would also be helpful to see the JSON structure that you are attempting to render :-)

**Edit:** Okay, so, I'm not 100% sure on this as I can't seem to find any documentation, but according to the [SproutCore Showcase](http://showcase.sproutcore.com/), you may need to ensure that your parent objects (those that have children) have a `group` attribute set to true. Please let us know if that helps or not!

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the "arrangedObjects" typo in the question text.

Moreover, I added the structure of the objects I created from the parsed JSON.

Comment: Did you try changing your `groupExampleView` to a `SC.SourceListGroupView`?

Comment: @DonJuwe Just updated my answer slightly with info about using a `group` attribute. Please see if it helps.